# Grant access to a sharing link in Graph API using application access

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting "There was an error processing the request." when I try to grant access to a sharing link in graph api using application access.
I do have "Files.ReadWrite.All, Sites.ReadWrite.All" permissions added to my API permissions.

I first tried to do it using the dotnet SDK, using the code snippets provided in graph api's documentation. Then I tried to do through HTTP and still got the same error as shown below with http status code 401.

`"error": { "code": "UnknownError", "message": "{\"Message\":\"There was an error processing the request.\",\"StackTrace\":\"\",\"ExceptionType\":\"\"}",`

This is the code I tried in dotnet, which is derived from graph api's documentation.

```cs
var sharePerm = await graphServiceClient.Drives[drive.Id].Items[folder.Id]
                .ItemWithPath(newFileName)
                .CreateLink.PostAsync(shareRequest);

            Console.WriteLine(JsonSerializer.Serialize(sharePerm));

            var shareUsersRequest = new Microsoft.Graph.Shares.Item.Permission.Grant.GrantPostRequestBody
            {
                Recipients = new List<DriveRecipient>
                {
                    new DriveRecipient
                    {
                        Email = "****@****.onmicrosoft.com",
                    },
                    new DriveRecipient
                    {
                        Email = "*****@*****.onmicrosoft.com",
                    },
                },
                Roles = new List<string>
                {
                    "read",
                },
            };

            var result = await graphServiceClient.Shares[sharePerm.ShareId].Permission.Grant.PostAsync(shareUsersRequest);
```

The link is getting created successfully, it is only the grant accesss that is not going through

Comment: Can you please decode your access token and check the scopes :https://jwt.io/, whether mentioned permissions are available.

Comment: @MehtabSiddique they do exist. this is directly from the access token
"roles": [
    "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All",
    "Sites.ReadWrite.All",
    "Files.ReadWrite.All"
  ],

Comment: I am also still getting an error (accessDenied) in the latest SDK, did you ever find a solution for this?